# A non-commutative analog of: two polynomials are algebraically dependent iff their Jacobian is zero

Tags: noncommutative-algebra, jacobians, transcendence, weyl-algebra

Let $f,g \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$.
There is a well-known result, that can be found for example 
[here](http://www.math.wayne.edu/~lml/lmlnotes.pdf), pages 19-20, that says the following:

> $f,g$ are algebraically dependent over $\mathbb{C}$ if and only if their Jacobian $Jac(f,g):=f_xg_y-f_yg_x$ is zero.

Actually, this result is valid for $f_1,\ldots,f_n \in \mathbb{C}[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$, any $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Now, let $f,g \in A_1(\mathbb{C})$, where $A_1(\mathbb{C})$
is the [first Weyl algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl_algebra) over $\mathbb{C}$, namely, the $\mathbb{C}$-algebra
generated by $x,y$ such that $[y,x]=yx-xy=1$.

I wonder if there exists an analog result to the above in $A_1(\mathbb{C})$,
namely:

> $f,g \in A_1(\mathbb{C})$ are 'algebraically dependent' over $\mathbb{C}$ if and only if $[f,g]=0$.

One has to be careful because:

(1) One has to define algebraic dependence over $\mathbb{C}$ of two non-commuting elements $f$ and $g$.
Should it be $\sum \lambda_{ij}f^ig^j=0$, with $\lambda_{ij} \in \mathbb{C}$ not all zero,
or $\sum \lambda_{ij}f^ig^j + \sum \mu_{ij}g^if^j=0$, with $\lambda_{ij},
\mu_{ij} \in \mathbb{C}$ not all zero?.
(Perhaps the first definition should be called 'one-sided algebraic dependence',
while the second definition should be called 'two-sided algebraic dependence').

(2) Perhaps [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/210438/commuting-elements-in-weyl-algebras-of-characteristic-zero) is relevant. The example there (of Dixmier) is of $U,V \in A_1$, $[U,V]=0$, and $U^3-V^2+1=0$, so it does not contradict my plausible analog result, since those $U$ and $V$ are algebraically dependent.

((3) I am not sure if this is relevant, but in the [above mentioned reference](http://www.math.wayne.edu/~lml/lmlnotes.pdf), on page 11, the [Gelfand-Kirillov dimension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfand%E2%80%93Kirillov_dimension) is mentioned with connection to transcendence degree; for $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ those notions coincide. Is the fact that the Gelfand-Kirillov dimension of $A_1(\mathbb{C})$ is two relevant to my question?).

Thank you very much for any help!

Comment: Since $x$ and $y$ are noncommuting formal variables, shouldn't your general noncommutative monomials rather be of the form $x^{0,1}y^{0,1}x^{0,1}y^{0,1}...$, where $0,1$ are the possible exponents? In other words, you should also have things like $fgf^2g^3fgf$.

Comment: @July, thank you for your comment. I think you are right. So the definition of algebraic dependence should be slightly more complicated than what I suggested.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reverse implication is true in a considerably more general setting (Burchnall-Chaundy theory). Namely, for any pair $(U,V)$ of commuting meromorphic coefficient differential operators in one variable of order at least one, there is a two-variable polynomial $P(z,w)$ such that $P(U,V)=0$ (the polynomial evaluation is unambiguous because $U$ and $V$ commute). There is an enormous body of literature on this topic related to integrable systems.

The proposed forward implication does not appear interesting or meaningful to me. (*However, see a very interesting formulation proposed by David Speyer in the comments.*) For example, the defining relation $yx-xy-1=0$ between $x$ and $y$ may be viewed as a form of "noncommutative algebraic dependence", yet of course $x$ and $y$ do not commute. And the proposed "one-sided algebraic dependence" need not have good formal properties, such as symmetry or transitivity. At best, one can attempt to extract such properties from commutativity.

Comment: A reasonable way to formulate the forward direction would be "any subalgebra of Gelfand-Kirillov dimension 1 is commutative." I don't know if it is true, but it isn't obviously false and seems to me to capture the intention of the question.

Comment: You are right, David, it is a nice formulation. I was too narrowly focused on coordinate formulation of algebraic dependence.

Comment: @VictorProtsak, thank you very much! I think that your answer is what I was looking for.

Comment: DavidSpeyer, nice idea, thank you. If I am not wrong, your statement is true, see https://ysharifi.wordpress.com/category/noncommutative-ring-theory-notes/gelfand-kirillov-dimension/, Algebras of GK dimension one, Theorem 2: ``Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field and let $A$ be a $k$-algebra. If $A$ is a domain and the GK dimension of $A$ is $\leq 1$, then $A$ is commutative". Perhaps it will be interesting to show the inverse statement: A commutative subalgebra of $A_1(\mathbb{C})$ has GK dimension at most one (perhaps this is a known result?).

Comment: @user237522 Victor's answer is 95% of the way to the inverse statement: He shows that, if $U$ and $V$ commute, then the ring generated by $U$ and $V$ has Krull dimension $1$. It follows from that the same is true for any finitely generated commutative subring. I bet you don't have to work much further to do all subalgebras whatsoever.

Comment: @DavidSpeyer, thanks. If I am not wrong, then also every non-finitely generated commutative subring has GK dimension one (by definition, it is the supremum on the GK dimensions of finitely generated subrings, and here every f.g. subring has GK dimension one).

Answer (score 1):

The first Weyl algebra over $C$ is isomorphic to the algebra of polynomials $C[x_1,x_2]$ equipped with a new multiplication, as follows:
define a linear operator $L$ on $C[x_1,x_2,y_1,y_2]$ to be the composite of partial differentiation w.r.t. $x_2$ and of partial differentiation w.r.t. $y_1$. Then $exp(L)$ defines an associative binary operation on $C[x_1,x_2]$ taking $f(x_1,x_2)$, $g(x_1,x_2)$ to the image of $exp(L)f(x_1,x_2)g(y_1,y_2)$ under the map taking the $y$s to $x$s. Sorry my lack of LaTeX skill prevents me writing this more elegantly. In fact, replacing $L$ by $tL$ gives you a $t$-parameter family of associative multiplications. By considering partial differentiation w.r.t. $t$ you can reduce the question of algebraic dependence in the Weyl algebra to that over the polynomial ring.